# Change layout weight for last row in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapterview, gridlayoutmanager

I need to display grid of items, with the last row centered, if it is not full.

I would like to achieve the following behavior:

[image: Required behavior]

I have started with `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager`, however, it looks like it is not possible to customize it this way.

I have to use some sort of `Adapter View`, because there might be huge number of elements.

What is the best way for implementing such design?

Comment: you can get the number of items in `getView` and then set gravity of last item depending on the number of items

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Did you find the solution?